# Google App Scripts shows my code ran but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an on edit code that is supposed to take the inputted state in column 5 and update the time zone. It also is supposed to take the DPD column and change the number to a negative if it's edited. The execution log shows the script completed but nothing changes on the spreadsheet.

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIOoq.png)

[Code that has allegedly run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXZ40.png)

```
function ListUpdate(e) {
  const cs = e.source;
  const cel = e.range;  
  const s1 = cs.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const trng = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TaBpBZN1dg57vjPt1ldZ1Cqdt-3JeWtmP_A9p-mI4Mk');
  const s2 = trng.getSheetByName("TimeZones");
  const ZONES = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const col = cel.getColumn();
  const rw = cel.getRow();

  if(s1 == '3193:RENA' &&  rw < 15){
    var val = cel.getValue();
      if(col == 5){
        for (var i=0;i<52;i++){
          if(ZONES[i][0] == val){
            tz = ZONES[i][2];
            cel.offset(0,1).setValue(tz);
            cel.setFontWeight(400)
          }
        }
      }
      else if(col == 7){
        cel.setValue("-"+dpd)
        cel.setFontWeight(400)
      }
  }
}
```

I've copy and pasted the exact same code with a static range and it works perfectly and I'm not sure why.

```
function Test(){
  const cs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cel = cs.getRange("G7");  
  const s1 = cs.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const trng = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TaBpBZN1dg57vjPt1ldZ1Cqdt-3JeWtmP_A9p-mI4Mk');
  const s2 = trng.getSheetByName("TimeZones");
  const ZONES = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const col = cel.getColumn();
  const rw = cel.getRow();


    if(s1 == '3193:RENA' &&  rw < 15){
    var val = cel.getValue();
      if(col == 5){
        for (var i=0;i<52;i++){
          if(ZONES[i][0] == val){
            tz = ZONES[i][2];
            cel.offset(0,1).setValue(tz);
            cel.setFontWeight(400)
          }
        }
      }
      else if(col == 7){
        cel.setValue("-"+val)
        cel.setFontWeight(400)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger for your code?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference I see is this line with that unknown variable: `cel.setValue("-"+dpd)` . May that be?

I suggest you use `Logger.log` inside each of the if statements so you can track where's the issue. Sometimes it's necessary to use `.toString()` or `*1` (for example) in some values to correctly match the types of data from difference sources, but you'll know better by logging. Try it and let me know what is printed

Comment: How would I use Logger.log within an onEdit code? I tried to previously to find out exactly what the values were but nothing shows in the execution log.

Comment: You should be able to add Logger.log inside each instance of your code to find the values. Then you do some edit in your Spreadsheet and access to the log in the Execution panel of the console (sometimes you have to wait some seconds until it's available). Use things that can help you track: `Logger.log("s1 is "+s1)` or `Logger.log("ZONES["+i+"][0] = "+ZONES[i][0])`

Comment: Thank you! I actually figured out what was wrong. In a not so bright moment I assumed onEdit meant any change (including overwrites that were the same value). The workaround I found is to clear the cell of the DPD value and re-input it.